# How to rewrite functions wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce plugin file `class-wc-booking-cart-manager.php` there is this code

```
/**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', array( $this, 'add_cart_item' ), 10, 1 );
        }

/**
     * Adjust the price of the booking product based on booking properties
     *
     * @param mixed $cart_item
     * @return array cart item
     */
    public function add_cart_item( $cart_item ) {
        if ( ! empty( $cart_item['booking'] ) && ! empty( $cart_item['booking']['_cost'] ) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['booking']['_cost'] );
        }
        return $cart_item;
    }
```

I want to change `add_cart_item` function's code into my child theme `functions.php` file

So I did this :

```
function custom_add_cart_item($cart_item) {
    if (empty( $cart_item['booking'] ) && empty( $cart_item['booking']['_cost'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price(2000);
    }
    return $cart_item;
}


function setup_add_cart_item_filter(){
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', array('WC_Booking_Cart_Manager', 'add_cart_item' ), 10, 1 );
    add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'custom_add_cart_item');
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup_add_cart_item_filter' );
```

But it does not work. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You may call `remove_all_filters('woocommerce_add_cart_item');` to remove existing hook, then call `add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'your_new_add_cart_item' );` in functions.php

**EDIT:** I missed a point that childtheme's `functions.php` is loaded before parent theme's, so running `remove_all_filters()` directly in functions.php is actually useless...

My updated answer is to wrap those calls in another function and call them after theme setup phrase:

```
function setup_add_cart_item_filter(){
    remove_all_filters('woocommerce_add_cart_item');
    add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'custom_add_cart_item');
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup_add_cart_item_filter' );
```

Comment: No. filters and actions should be evaluated only when corresponding events are triggered.

Comment: Still not working, altough I replace remove_all_filters by this line : 
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', array('WC_Booking_Cart_Manager', 'add_cart_item' ), 10, 1 );

Comment: Do you know if the old, new, or both add_cart_item() is called now?

Comment: Yes, the old one is still called

Comment: Try `add_action( 'init', 'setup_add_cart_item_filter' );`